# Expected order of magnitude of character sums under GRH

Tags: reference-request, analytic-number-theory, character-sums

Let $\chi$ be a nonprincipal character with modulus $q$. Under GRH, what is the expected order of magnitude of $\sum_{n \le x} \chi(n)$, where I think of $x$ and $q$ as growing, but $x$ is smaller than $q$?

A bit more formally, I am interested in conditional upper bounds for 
$$F(x,q) = \max_{\chi_0 \neq \chi \bmod q}|\sum_{n \le x} \chi(n)|$$
as $x$ tends to infinity, with $q \ge x$.  This includes both known bounds and connjectural bounds. I am mostly interested in the case that $q$ is a prime power, but not only.
For example, [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1071579717300321) (equation (2)) it is observed that $F(x,q) = O(\sqrt{x} \exp(\log q /\log \log q))$ under GRH.